# What substance do they use to grease bottom bracket, crank, pedal bolts etc?

Tags: bottom-bracket, lubricant, grease

When watching bike assembly videos I wonder what substance do they use to grease carving of bottom bracket, fork, crank, pedals etc? Here is video and screenshot example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about what is used to lube the *bearings*, or what is used to lube *threads* such as in bottom brackets?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus generally speaking I want to know each lube type and usage areas in bicycle. I know about chain and bearings but lube for bottom bracket as in screenshot is mystery for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bottom bracket and most bicycle components , generally it is just a multi-purpose bicycle grease, on bottom brackets anti-seize should be used if it is a titanium frame or mismatched metal that are known to seize or bond to one another, but can be used in other frames as well. I have also heard of people using teflon tape that is made for pipes etc. Although for most applications including pedals, headset, crank and so on a general use grease is perfectly fine.

The following are all common and a lot comes down to personal preference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the advantage of using it instead of nothing?

Comment: It seals water out from getting inside the bearings and moving parts and prevents corrosion as well as metals seizing together making them easy to remove and service. Moving parts need lubrication and grease stays put for long periods of time in addition to protecting seals and such from water and dust. It also reduces friction so that moving parts such as bearings do not wear down as quickly. I would recommend always using it over not using any.

Comment: Thanks, another question. I have a large packet of graphite lubricant that I bought for bearings a while ago. Can I also use it to grease carvings?

Comment: Is it the powdered graphite or a graphite impregnated liquid? If it's the powder it would probably work for awhile but not nearly as well as grease. Mainly because grease stays put and resists water, thinner graphite lubricant does not. Water resistance is the main reason to use grease. You can also use general purpose grease from an auto parts store which is often times cheaper than bicycle specific grease. Which if possible i think it would definitely be worth getting a proper grease rather than the graphite stuff, its not really designed for this sort of application.

Comment: @vladdihoney see related answer from last week https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/49414/9016